# How to make dynamic object properties available for parent component inside v-for in child one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a child component that uses v-for. Here is the child component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in listItems"
                :key=item.id>
                <span>{{item.name}} - {{item.color}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            listItems: Array
        }
    };
</script>
```

`listItems` is an Array of objects.

My question is: How do I make the property names in between the `<span>` tags dynamic from the parent component? Depending on the array of objects passed into the props as `listItems`, sometimes I may want the text in the `<span>` tags to be different based on the properties of the objects in the array. For example:

```
<span>{{item.id}} - {{item.location}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) as follows :

```
   <li v-for="item in listItems"
                :key=item.id>
               <slot v-bind:item="item">
                 <span>{{item.name}} - {{item.color}}</span>
               </slot>
            </li>
```

then you use it as you like :

```
<child> 
  <template v-slot:default="{item}">
   <span>{{item.id}} - {{item.location}}</span>
  </template>
</child>
```

or

```
<child> 
  <template v-slot:default="{item}">
   <p>{{item.location}}</p>
  </template>
</child>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few different ones you're using, you could have a series of `<span v-if="item.id">{{item.id}}</span> - <span v-if="item.foo">{{item.foo}}</span>`